# Getting array from imshow without plotting it

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(img, cmap=cm.jet)`. `img` is a 2D matrix. The 
resulting image is with color so I think the colormap add 3 color channels to the image.

How can I retrieve the image as a numpy array (including the 3 color channels) without first saving the image or plotting the image using `imshow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
norm = plt.Normalize(img.min(), img.max())
numpy_array = cm.jet(norm(img))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also possible to save a 2D matrix as an image (grayscale) without changing the underlying matrix (e.g. not clipping values above 1 to 1)? That means when I read in the image again I would like to get the same matrix.